# Ajax call to PHP not returning succesfull

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Problem here is that my Ajax call is failing.
`alert(RealMessage);` is called, so I know that this function is entered, but the `"MSG SENT"` alert is not called, which tells me that this Ajax request is failing. I thought that in order for a PHP request to return success is if the script runs. Even thought I'm not returning anything would I in a way need to echo something back in order to signal that it is succesfull?

JS:

```
$("#EnteredMessage").submit(function(){
    var RealMessage = document.getElementById("message").value;
    alert(RealMessage);
    $.ajax({
        url:"sendmessage.php",
        data: {msg:RealMessage},
        type:"POST",
        datatype: "JSON",
        success: function(){
            console.log("Message sent");
            alert("MSG SENT");
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$message = $_POST["msg"];

$filecreate = fopen("messages.txt","w");

fwrite($filecreate,$message);
fclose($filecreate);
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: In php file return the json response.
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'success');
exit

Comment: sent some status to your js from your php script(sendmessage.php) like die(json_encode(array('status'=>'Success')));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP , echo the result with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
<?php

$message = $_POST["msg"];

$filecreate = fopen("messages.txt","w");

fwrite($filecreate,$message);
fclose($filecreate);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>"your result"));
```

in your jQuery code `datatype` is an incorrect keyword . `dataType` is the correct keyword , and wrap the `keys` in `data` with quotes , then in ajax success  console.log the returned `data_result`

```
$("#EnteredMessage").submit(function(){
    var RealMessage = document.getElementById("message").value;
    alert(RealMessage);
    $.ajax({
        url:"sendmessage.php",
        data: {'msg':RealMessage},
        type:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data_result){
            console.log(data_result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Use `json_encode` [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
echo json_encode(array("status"=>'success'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes you need to return some json response by echo that result.see the below code.

In php

```
<?php

$message = $_POST["msg"];

$filecreate = fopen("messages.txt","w");

fwrite($filecreate,$message);
fclose($filecreate);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>'Message sent!!!'));  //you can sent any thing

?>
```